# How to Sum All Columns from Temp Table in Microsoft SQL Server Like Value Counts in Pandas

Tags: sql-server

I have a temp table called #My_Temp_Table that holds 1s and 0s across 200+ columns in MS SQL Server that I need to sum the values of each column.  For the SUM(), I don't want to individually write out each column name, so I'm looking for a way to loop through the names of the columns.  To get all of the column names for my temp table, I have the following code:

```
SELECT col_names
FROM Tempdb.Sys.Columns
WHERE Object_ID = Object_ID('tempdb..#My_Temp_Table')
```

Then, I basically want to do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(SELECT col_names
FROM Tempdb.Sys.Columns
WHERE Object_ID = Object_ID('tempdb..#My_Temp_Table'))
FROM #My_Temp_Table
```

Comment: Please give an example of what the column names would be named?

Comment: I would like the column names to be named as they appear as the result of this query: SELECT col_names
FROM Tempdb.Sys.Columns
WHERE Object_ID = Object_ID('tempdb..#My_Temp_Table')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've compiled the below for you.

```
if exists(select name from Tempdb.Sys.Columns where Object_ID = Object_ID('tempdb..#My_Temp_Table'))
drop table #My_Temp_Table
go

if exists(select name from Tempdb.Sys.Columns where Object_ID = Object_ID('tempdb..#Temp_Table2'))
drop table #Temp_Table2
go

create table #My_Temp_Table
(   column1 float
,   column2 float
,   column3 float
,   column4 float
,   column5 float   )

insert into #My_Temp_Table
(   column1
,   column2
,   column3
,   column4
,   column5 )
values
    (1,0,3,5,3)
,   (2,2,0,5,5)
,   (0,7,0,3,0)

create table #Temp_Table2
(   [column] varchar(100) ,results  float   )

declare @loop int
,       @sqlCommand varchar(max)
,       @columnname varchar(100)
,       @result1    float   =   0
,       @result2    float   =   0

declare @ColumnTable table (id int identity primary key, columnname varchar(100))
insert into @ColumnTable (columnname)
select name
from Tempdb.Sys.Columns
where Object_ID = Object_ID('tempdb..#My_Temp_Table')

begin
    select @Loop = min(id) FROM @ColumnTable
    while @Loop IS NOT NULL
        begin
            select  @columnname =   (select columnname from @ColumnTable where id = @Loop)
            insert  #Temp_Table2 ([column]) select @columnname
            select @Loop = min(id) FROM @ColumnTable where id>@Loop
        end
end

set @sqlCommand = (select top 1  stuff((select distinct ',sum('+[column] + ') '+[column] from #Temp_Table2 for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as lookup from #Temp_Table2)
set @sqlCommand = 'select '+@sqlCommand+' from #My_Temp_Table'
exec (@sqlCommand)
```

Would this work?

The result of this is in each column as requested and can be seen below:

[image]

Comment: Wow this looks like a lot of work - but I'm not looking for a grand total, just a total for each column - so col_1: 12, col_2: 14, col_3: 10

Comment: O then I misunderstood you, because the above sum's each column together as well...

Comment: I've changed my answer to what you require, will this suffice?

Comment: So this loops through all of the columns correctly but then returns NULL values for all columns instead of the sum totals for each column.  Any thoughts?